# Pivot table using postgres sql

Tags: sql, postgresql, pivot, transpose

I have this query

```
select filing_date_id, form_type,count('form_type') as "number_of_form"
from finance_db.sec_edgar se
where bloomberg_ticker='INTU US'
group by filing_date_id, form_type, bloomberg_ticker 
order by filing_date_id desc
```

that ,as a result, it gives me a table which looks like this:

```
"filing_date_id" "form_type" "number_of_form"
20220210         SC          1
20220203         4           2
20220201         SC          1
20220124         8-K         1
20220124         4           10
```

I want to create a pivot table which as a column has the variable "form_type" and inside there is the variable "number_of_form"

```
"filing_date_id" "SC "4" "8-K"
20220210          1   0    0
20220203          0   2    0
20220201          1   0    0
20220124          0   10   1
```

Keep in mind there are many other variables in form_type that I have not show you here and the db is postgres. I tried to use the PIVOT function but it doesn't seem to work at all.

Comment: Consider this: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/tablefunc.html, specifically `crosstabN`

Comment: I saw this but my code seems not working and I don't how I can do. I tried `select *
from crosstab(
'select filing_date_id, form_type,count("form_type") as "number_of_form"
from finance_db.sec_edgar se
where bloomberg_ticker="INTU US"
group by filing_date_id, form_type, bloomberg_ticker 
order by filing_date_id desc'
)`

Comment: `count('form_type')` is equivalent of `count(*)` - single quotes define string lterals.

Comment: I still don't get how to run this, can you please write me down the whole query please?